# Installing libevent extension for php on Centos

Tags: centos, php, web-server, configuration, php.ini

How to install the [libevent extension](http://libevent.org/) for php on Centos 7?

I spent many many hours trying this, googling many times and really really struggled, so I'm going to document my own answer to this in the hope I help someone else.

I tried firstly on a MAC where I was attempting something along the lines of:

```
phpize
sh autogen.sh
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

I never actually achieved this way, running into many errors on the way, so I installed Centos and used `yum` to finally get the extension working.  If anyone can explain the above method as well, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have listed all the steps as if you have selected 'minimum installation' for Centos 7, that way I should cover most people's setups on Centos, as no dependencies are assumed.  I'm not a Linux guru, so some steps may seem unnecessary.

`Yum install net-tools.` - Allows ifconfig to check IP address (useful if it's a local VM).

`Yum install php` - Installs php version 5.4.16 (you might have an error with PHP 5.5 and greater.  You can check what php version will be installed by running yum info php

`Yum install php-mysql` - Installs mysql and the pdo extensions php requires for many things.

`yum install php-pear` - install php-pear
    installing pear allows pecl command.

`Yum install php-devel` - To install libevent, you will need the command phpize, php-devel contains this.

`Yum install gcc` - You will also need C compiler to install libevent, which gcc provides.

`Yum install libevent-devel` - This installs the libevent ‘headers’ that pecl install libevent requires.

`Pecl install libevent` - This will actually result in error, but is useful in giving you the channel url to use instead, currently channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.1.0

`Pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.1.0` - This is the final step that will (hopefully) install libevent without any errors.

Add `extension=libevent.so` to `php.ini` - Although libevent is installed, you need to tell php to reference it on startup.

`Apachectl restart` - Restarts apache / php

`sudo iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` - this will allow connections from web browser.

Can now check it’s there by looking up ‘libevent’ by running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`  By default, web files should go in `/var/www/html`.

Comment: `php-pear` is in the base EL7 repos, there is no need to get it from remirepo.  Since you already started installing stock php packages, you should stick with stock.

Answer (score 2):

`php-pecl-event` is available via the [EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), built against the stock version of PHP.

Enable EPEL:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Install the PECL module:

```
yum install php-pecl-event
```

Comment: Great!  Is there an alternative for Homebrew / Port do you know so I can get it installed on MacOSX Capitan as well?

Comment: No idea, I don't use Mac.

Comment: I found you can install PECL on mac using `curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar` and `sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar` then from there you can install `pecl install libevent-devel` and `Pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.1.0`